# Get latest version - TFS - show Output window automatically

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, output-window

I have a habit to close windows: Find Results, Output, etc. when working with Visual Studio.

And when I am executing "Get latest version" for a solution there is often .. nothing. So I don't know if it's for real finished taking synchronizing local version without errors or if I missclick menu item.

I have to open View - Output and do "Get latest version" again because sometimes Source Control output from Output window is completely blank there.

There is an option

> Tools - Options - Project and Solution - General - Show Output window when build starts

I want similar for TFS. Is there a way to automatically open Output window when executing "Get latest version"?

Comment: Do you select "Code source control - Team foundation" as output in the output window?

Comment: @Troopers, yes if you refer to the problem what Output window is blank sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any settings to launch Output window automatically when "Get Latest" finished. I recommend you to set the Output Window to "Auto Hide" so that the window is hide automatically when you perform other actions.